# Jquery .next() is not working

Tags: jquery

I am populating the following html structure with days that will include the day of the week as well as the day of the month. The first "day" is populated as expected but using `.next()` I am not able to change the siblings in `resultsContainer`. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="eventInfoWindow">
    <div id="dayOneEvents" class="eventContainers">
        <div id="dayOneHeader" class="eventHeaders">
            <p id="dayOneDay" class="eventDay"></p>
            <p id="dayOneWeek" class="eventWeek"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dayTwoEvents" class="eventContainers">
        <div id="dayTwoHeader" class="eventHeaders">
            <p id="dayTwoDay" class="eventDay"></p>
            <p id="dayTwoWeek" class="eventWeek"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dayThreeEvents" class="eventContainers">
        <div id="dayThreeHeader" class="eventHeaders">
            <p id="dayThreeDay" class="eventDay"></p>
            <p id="dayThreeWeek" class="eventWeek"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dayFourEvents" class="eventContainers">
        <div id="dayFourHeader" class="eventHeaders">
            <p id="dayFourDay" class="eventDay"></p>
            <p id="dayFourWeek" class="eventWeek"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dayFiveEvents" class="eventContainers">
        <div id="dayFiveHeader" class="eventHeaders">
            <p id="dayFiveDay" class="eventDay"></p>
            <p id="dayFiveWeek" class="eventWeek"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

relevant jquery

```
    $('#searchResultsContainer').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,255,0,0.3)");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        },
        click: function () {
            $.post("getClassEvents.php", {
                    id: $(this).attr("id")
                },
                function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $(".eventHeaders > p").text("");
                    $(".eventContainers > div:not(.eventHeaders) ").children().remove();
                    var dateDays = data.split("@")[0].split(",");
                    var resultsContainer = $(".eventHeaders").first();
                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        resultsContainer.find(".eventDay").text(dateDays[i].split(".")[0]);
                        resultsContainer.find(".eventWeek").text(dateDays[i].split(".")[1]);
                        resultsContainer = resultsContainer.next();
                    }

                });
        }
    }, " div");
```

Comment: Just make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). We can test easier that way.

Comment: I don't see `resultsContainer` listed in your `HTML`.

Comment: It's a jquery object not an html element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.eventHeaders` does not have any siblings in the DOM. It is the only element inside it's parent at that level.

Instead set your resultsContainer to `.eventContainers`, as that has the siblings you are after.

```
var resultsContainer = $(".eventContainers").first();
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    resultsContainer.find(".eventDay").text(dateDays[i].split(".")[0]);
    resultsContainer.find(".eventWeek").text(dateDays[i].split(".")[1]);
    resultsContainer = resultsContainer.next();
}
```

**Edit**

Or you could use the jquery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to do this in a much neater way:

```
$(".eventHeaders").each(function (index) {
    $(this).find(".eventDay").text(dateDays[index].split(".")[0]);
    $(this).find(".eventWeek").text(dateDays[index].split(".")[1]);
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had used `.eventContainers` at first but it wouldn't work. There must have been an error elsewhere in my code that was changed in searching. I was initially trying to store all of the `eventHeader` elements in a jquery object but when I tried to access them by index `resultsContainer[i]` it wouldn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Those indexed objects were raw Dom, had to wrap them with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Your `resultsContainer` is populated by `$(".eventHeaders")` and that is a sibling of the `.eventContainers`

So since you want to go to the next `.eventContainers` element you should populate it with

```
var resultsContainer = $(".eventContainers").first();
```

---

If you look at the docs you will see that [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) works with siblings (*and siblings mean elements that share the same parent*)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are targeting `.eventHeaders` as your `resultsContainer`.

`.next()` is used when `objects` are on the same plane (`siblings`).

Try targeting `.eventContainers` instead.